# Достать url из WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Я новичок в сфере разработки под android, помогите пожалуйста достать url текущей страницы

```
package ru.test.testcomp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* разворачиваем приложение на весь экран */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        /* применяем наш лейаут к текущему экрану */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* находим WebView элемент по его id */
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

        /* создаем новые настройки для нашего WebView элемента */
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webView.loadUrl("http://test.ru");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А что не так? Напишите в вопросе

Comment: @gil9red дело в том, что я не знаю даже как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать метод [getUrl()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()):

```
String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
```